# Последовательные промисы js или подменяющая функция

Tags: javascript, promise

Может быть идея странная, но необходимая так,как (не с примером про `hello()`)
возникла проблема того, что начинается одна функция, и сразу за ней js решает запустить другу, а эта другая функция по сути делает подмену данных(что заставило 2 часика искать ошибку) если знаете более лучший метод избежание этой проблемы чем промисы, пожалуйста скажите его.

Есть массив обьектов, у каждого есть функция например `hello()`. Нужно реализовать вызов этой функции у каждого обьекта последовательно, с помощью промисов, так чтобы при выполнении функции одного обьекта промис становился resolved, создавал новый промис который ожидает выполнения функции след. обьекта и так далее до конца.

```
class Obj {
    constructor(id){
        this.id = id;
    }

    hello(){
        alert(this.id);
    }
}
let arr = [];
for(let i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    arr.push(new Obj(i));
}
```

И нужно заставить каждый обьект массива arr с помощью промисов последовательно отзываться.

Comment: Добавьте код к вопросу! Словесное описание - это хорошо, когда оно дополнено кодом. Поторопился с комментом) У вас `hello` не возвращает `promise`.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko прочитайте новое изменение причины выбраного пути, и идея в том что не hello промисами оперируют а наоборот

Comment: Пояснение не помогло. Если у вас `hello` не возвращает промис и она асинхронная, то вы не сможете дождаться ее окончания.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko я думал что будет наподие этого: промис исполняет функцию и когда он завершается, он создаст новый промис , который исполняет уже следующий елемент массива и так до конца

Comment: Промис не может исполнять функцию, он не для этого существует. Все равно не понятно, чего вы хотите добиться.